# targeting the parent with location.href

Tags: javascript, location-href

I have an interactive map that is set in an iframe in a word press web page. the links are passed to a javascript function. when I click on a link on the map I want it to go to another web page altogether, but it keeps loading that web page into the iframe no matter what I try.

I tried 3 different ways of linking to it in the javascript.

```
function go2Link(e,link) {
    var code = (e.code ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 13) {
    //window.parent.location.href = link;
    //window.open(link)
    window.parent.open(link);
    }
}
```

But instead of it going to a new web page, the web page does not seem to break out of the iframe and gets downsized inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried window.parent().open(link); ?
And otherwise I think you can try window.parent().parent().open(link); if that doesn't work.

Comment: yes i actually tried all of those. still targets the iframe instead.

Comment: I'm thinking the fact that the iframe is contained within a word press page is why it's having "parent issues"?

Answer (score 0):

```
    window.parent.open(link, '_blank');
```

This will open that link in another tab itself.
Cheers

Comment: i tried everything and still it keeps loading into the iframe. very stubborn! i even checked the iframe source to make sure it was being updated with the latest code. Site is here http://www.simba.psu.edu/map/. If you click on September (right in the middle where the text is) it should go to https://sites.psu.edu/simbapsu/map/journey/#ongoing but that page instead gets loaded inside the iframe. If you click on the edge of the white circle, the link is controlled by a separate href that goes to the right place. had to use 2 sets of links for accessibility (screen readers & tabbed navigation).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. that particular link was missig the target="_parent" tag the others had in the normal a href tag. it wasn't in the javascript link at all. that was working fine. dummy me.